# Python returning false on checking if a string exists in list even when it does

Tags: python, django

I imported a model(named Feature) and set it to a list in Django

```
posts = Feature.objects.order_by('name')
```

upon calling the 5th element
`print(posts[5])` this displays apple in shell which is the 5th object
however on checking it with a if condition it returns false

```
if 'apple' in posts:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

and it prints no .. why is this happening even tho apple exists in the list

Comment: It's happening because `"apple"` is not in the list. You claim that it is, but you haven't actually provided a [mcve]. It may look like `'apple'` is in your list, but it isn't.

Comment: Can you provide the the value of posts please ?

Comment: What are you talking about guys? It's enough to deduce what's happening :)

Comment: <QuerySet [<Feature: apple>, <Feature: banana>, <Feature: blueberrry>, <Feature: guava>, <Feature: mango>, <Feature: orange>]>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'apple'` is a string object. `posts` is not a `list` but `QuerySet` object of `Feature` objects.
It will never find object of other type :)

You have to seek `Feature` objects like that, in example:

```
apple = Feature.objects.get(name='apple')
# or if you have more than one
apple = Feature.objects.filter(name='apple').first()

posts = Feature.objects.order_by('name') 

if apple in posts:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

it will print `yes`.

PS If name is going to be `unique` you can add `unique=True` to the model.

Comment: Not possible. Don't you still have `apple` in `''`? In my example it's a variable, not a string.

Comment: Maybe `if any('apple' in feature.name for feature in posts):`?

Comment: Yes it works now , I had to create a new variable and name and now i can check if that new variable is in list tysm

Comment: @Electrocuted just remember, that `QuerySet` is something more (much better) that just a list :)

Comment: this method added a new apple in my database (other than the existing apple) . Can I somehow avoid this?

Comment: Of course, use: `Feature.objects.get(name='apple')` or if you have more than one: `Feature.objects.filter(name='apple').first()`. Like I said, I only gave you example how it works. Corrected to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to just run `queryset`

1. for if the string is `Case-insensitive`

```py
    fruit = "apple"     
    posts = Feature.objects.filter(name__icontains = "apple")
    if posts.exists():
       print("yes")
    else:
       print("No")
```

2. for `Case-insensitive exact match`

```py
        fruit = "apple"
        posts = Feature.objects.filter(name__iexact= "apple")
        if posts.exists():
           print("yes")
        else:
           print("No")
```